# Button Url to send whatsapp msg with auto attached pdf file from local downloads

Tags: php, html, href, whatsapp

I want to make a button in html and php, when clicked whatsapp web should open with the entered number and also with auto attached pdf from local storage.

send

Comment: The code i am using is: <a href="web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9199999999&attachment=c:\\users\downloads/abc.pdf" >send</a>

Comment: Put the code to the body of the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0):

don't use `web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=9199999999&attachment=c:\\users\downloads/abc.pdf`

use `wa.me/send?phone=9199999999&attachment=c://users/downloads/abc.pdf`

add the country code to the number and replace the `+` in `00`

Comment: Eymen, i did it, but it is only opening chat for that number and it is not attaching the desired file on that chat. Please help

Comment: I think the problem is in the path, if this file is fixed you can upload it and but the url, else you can put the file in the same path as the link's page

Comment: are you sure?? it's not working for me